# Java: GetResource from different folder

Tags: javafx, getresource

I am trying to make 3 folders in a `Javafx` application. I have a `Views` folder which will contain my views, and I want to load an `fxml` file saved inside `Views`. I wrote this code inside `start` method:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Views/ProductView.fxml"));
```

My folders are structured as follows:
[image]

Apparently `GetResources()` can't find my file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the proble is that you have no `/View` but  `/application/View` can you try that? However you may also try `View/` since your Main class is in the 'application' package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this something like this
`Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassloader().getResource("application/Models/Views/ProductView.fxml")`

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that loader cannot find fxml file ...
So, load method can be either empty or gets Inputstream argument.
And this should work:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/java/CRUD/bnkseekCRUD.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load(fileInputStream);
```

At least it works for me. )))